# build and deploy project with laravel + vue js + inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, build

Good afternoon, I put together a project for deployment on the VDS, through npm run build and it does not work, it gives errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj1Hy.png)
npm run dev works and everything connects perfectly.
My vite.config.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCObV.png)

My app.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr1lV.png)

Inertia js for laravel is connected
I cleaned this and wrote without it, it doesn't help. The problem is this. if you remove the templates, then the component works (partially). I assume that perhaps the settings are incorrect in the configs or for some reason it does not work...

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, it consisted in the template error, js not within tag this.